# Could not make shiro-redis work in vaadin flow spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, shiro, vaadin-flow

I'm trying to configure shiro redis session storage for vaadin spring boot app. but application failed whenever I try to set **redisSessionDao** to **SessionMananger**. application able to run if I remove **redisSessionDao** from **SessionMananger** but still can't persist session to redis. And also when I debug I save session is instance of **DelegatingSubject$StopingAwareProxiedSession** it should be **SimpleSession**, this caused Serializable issue when I try to save session manually using **redisSessionDao**.

Here is my configuration

```
import kh.gov.tax.gdtict.security.listener.CoreSessionListener;
import kh.gov.tax.gdtict.security.realm.JwtRealm;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSessionStorageEvaluator;
import org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSubjectDAO;
import org.apache.shiro.realm.Realm;
import org.apache.shiro.session.SessionListener;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
import org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean;
import org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager;
import org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie;
import org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager;
import org.crazycake.shiro.RedisCacheManager;
import org.crazycake.shiro.RedisManager;
import org.crazycake.shiro.RedisSessionDAO;
import org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {

    @Bean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager) {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/login");
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/login");
        Map<String,String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/login", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "authc");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/coremgm/public/**", "anon");

        // Internal Resources
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/icons/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/images/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/fonts/**", "anon");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/static/**", "anon");

        // 3rd Parties Resources
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**/*.js", "anon");

        // Authentication
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/coremgm/**", "authc");

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public Realm realm() {
        JwtRealm jwtRealm = new JwtRealm();
        jwtRealm.setCachingEnabled(false);
        return jwtRealm;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager,
                                                                RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager) {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();

        securityManager.setRealm(realm());
        securityManager.setSessionManager(sessionManager);
        securityManager.setCacheManager(redisCacheManager);


        // Disable session storage for security reason
        DefaultSubjectDAO subjectDAO = new DefaultSubjectDAO();
        DefaultSessionStorageEvaluator defaultSessionStorageEvaluator = new DefaultSessionStorageEvaluator();
        defaultSessionStorageEvaluator.setSessionStorageEnabled(false);
        subjectDAO.setSessionStorageEvaluator(defaultSessionStorageEvaluator);
        securityManager.setSubjectDAO(subjectDAO);
        return securityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public List<SessionListener> listeners() {
        List<SessionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        listeners.add(new CoreSessionListener());
        return listeners;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManager(RedisSessionDAO redisSessionDAO) {
        DefaultWebSessionManager sessionManger = new DefaultWebSessionManager();
        sessionManger.setSessionDAO(redisSessionDAO);
        sessionManger.setGlobalSessionTimeout(300000);
        sessionManger.setSessionIdUrlRewritingEnabled(false);
        sessionManger.setSessionListeners(this.listeners());
        sessionManger.setSessionValidationSchedulerEnabled(true);
        sessionManger.setDeleteInvalidSessions(true);
        sessionManger.setSessionIdCookieEnabled(true);
        sessionManger.setSessionIdCookie(cookie());
        sessionManger.setSessionIdCookie(new SimpleCookie("JSESSIONID"));
        sessionManger.setSessionValidationInterval(300000);
        return sessionManger;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisManager redisManager() {
        RedisManager redisManager = new RedisManager();
        redisManager.setHost("127.0.0.1:6379");
        return redisManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisSessionDAO redisSessionDAO(RedisManager redisManager) {
        RedisSessionDAO redisSessionDAO = new RedisSessionDAO();
        redisSessionDAO.setSessionInMemoryEnabled(false);
        redisSessionDAO.setRedisManager(redisManager);
        return redisSessionDAO;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(RedisManager redisManager) {
        RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager();
        redisCacheManager.setPrincipalIdFieldName("id");
        redisCacheManager.setRedisManager(redisManager);
        return redisCacheManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator getDefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator = new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
        defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.setProxyTargetClass(true);
        return defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor(org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager securityManager) {
        AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
        authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        return authorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor;
    }
}
```

And here is error logs

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.unlockSession(VaadinService.java:822)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:841)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:697)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1534)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:246)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-09 10:36:25.664 [  http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: null
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:151)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:457)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.unlockSession(VaadinService.java:822)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findOrCreateVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:841)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.findVaadinSession(VaadinService.java:697)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1534)
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:246)
    at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help to correct what what's wrong with my configuration!! Thanks

Comment: There seems to be problem with session locking. Vaadin tries to unlock session lock, which it does not own. This does not necessarily mean that issue is in Vaadin, it just bubbles up in this point. So this indicates that locks have gone out of sync in some phase. Actually this is quite common problem with session replication.

Comment: You could check this question from Vaadin Forum for further details https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18177393